# Adding choices of two dropdown boxes into one string in Acrobat form

Tags: javascript, string, adobe, dropdown, acrobat

I have been unsuccessfully searching for the solution for two days.....

Basically, I have two dropdown boxes and one text field, so the choice of either or both of them must go in the text field. The choices in the dropdown boxes are identical, but because of language specifics, the strings they return are slightly different.

My problem is that I can't seem to find a way to get the string from both of the dropdown boxes into the text field. If I have a choice from one of them, then it's ok. But I can't get a string from both of them.... It's like the choices do not combine into one simple string....

Hopefully that makes sense.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set the text box value to be calculated and then set the custom calculation script to something like...

```
event.target.value = this.getField("dropdown1").value + ", "+this.getField("dropdown2").value
```

Adjust the comma delimiter as you see fit.